# Pause the thread execution on service when onPause is called in an activity

Tags: java, android, multithreading, synchronization, android-service

When an activity enters into pause state, `onPause()` method will be called and then `unregisterReceiver(mReceiver)` method in `onPause()` is called.

An example:

```java
// in the Activity class
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Log.d("called", "onPause");
        super.onPause();
        SearchFileService.PauseSearching = true;
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }

// in the Service class
public class SearchFileService extends Service {
public static Boolean PauseSearching = false;


public void run(){
...
while(!searchingStack.isEmpty()){
    while(PauseSearching){};// infinite loop to pause execution

// to start search operations

}//while


}//run
}//service
```

Only the receiver is not listening to broadcast but the service still keeps running when `onPause()` is called.  In my example, I created a new thread on service to search certain files. When the activity is paused, it keeps searching. I have tried the following approach but it is not efficient.

I add this line `while(PauseSearching){};` to the searching function and when `onPause` is called, the var  `PauseSearching` is set to be `true`. Thus the code enters into an infinite loop, pausing the thread execution.

Questions:

1. Are there any good approaches to pause the thread running in a service when an activity is on `onPause` state?
2. I think the first approach is very inefficient, is that strange to use infinite loop for execution pause?
3. `Wait`, `notify`, and `synchronization`. Then I try to add `wait()` and `notify()` method to synchronize the execution. But I don't know what should I write in the `onPause()` method and where should put `wait()`, `notify()` and `syncrhozied`.

Any advice is welcome. :))))) Thanks.

Comment: first of all thread pause is not guaranteed anyway...

Comment: @AndroidKiller Why is that? `Thread.interrupt` or `sleep()` can't do that?

Comment: It would be good if you add more code snippets in your query such as what is happening in the boradcast onReceive and how it is called and where the service is starting and stopping. Further if you want to controll service execution only then you can simply stop your service in onPause() and in onStart() start the service again.

Comment: @Alston sleep will do the thread to hang on for few milliseconds but it won't leave the resources and interrupt won't guarantee as far as i have knowledge though not 100% not sure.

Comment: have you tried `thread.suspend()` ?

Comment: @PrachiSingh It's deprecated.